# How to display a form on a small screen

Tags: html, forms, mobile

I am trying to create a single web page that will display easily on a mobile device, but I am having trouble and was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction.  Please understand that I am new to programming and am learning as I go.

Unfortunately I can not figure out hot to show my code here, but here is a link to the page in question:

[Form for mobile devices](http://cigarpipesmokerinsurance.com/mobile.html)

Does anyone see anything that would prevent my form from showing up on a smaller screen without having to use scroll bars?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having?

Comment: I added a question below the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you drop the fixed-width table layout for your form and use a natual flowing layout instead. Here is an example of the first couple of fields:

```
<form name="contactinfo" method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Application Request Form</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Full Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">E-Mail</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </div>
        ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This will immediately help the layout adjust to different devices and it is also better mark-up for the form.

Other recommendations:

- Put all your styles in CSS.
- Move your JavaScript to the bottom of the page (i.e. the validation function)
- Consider whether you really need a reset button? What's the use case for it?

Comment: Thank you so much for the examples and recommendations.  I agree there is no real use for the reset button.  If I were to move the JavaScript to the bottom of the page, would that be below the end body tag?

Comment: Also, I see that you used input type email for the email address.  Would you recommend that I then remove the validate email function as it seems html5 automatically validates that input type?

Comment: @Chupacabraj - Place your javascript just before the end body tag, not after it. You can rely on just the HTML5 validating of the email input if you're happy with older browsers not being compatible with it.

Comment: @Chupacabraj the primary reason for using the HTML5 input types, such as `type="email"` is that it offers mobile users better keyboard options for software keyboards. For example, on iPhone, if you use `type="text"` the user has to navigate to a different keyboard to find the ampersat (@). Whereas it will automatically be included if you use `type="email"`. The validation is handy, but anything you validate client-side you still need validate server-side.